# Date popup - how to restrict typing into the textfield and return timestamp instead of formated date

Tags: 7, datetime

In D7 I'm using date popup form element:

```
$form['sidebar']['reg_date']['from'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#title' => t('From:'),
);
```

When user click the textfield a popup calendar will appear, but user also can type the date into the textfield. But he can write something invalid like '44444' and this value will be returned in form state values without any form error. It would be useful if this module had an option for restricting typing date by keyboard. Is there any option for this?

I also have one side question: Is there any option to return unix timestamp value instead of formatted date in form state values? In my case it returns date in format '29.5.2016'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `['#attributes'] = array('readonly' => 'readonly');`

Ex:

```
    $date_format = 'd/m/Y H:i';
    $form['campaign_popup'] = array(
          '#type' => 'date_popup',
          '#date_format' => $date_format,
          '#default_value' => variable_get('campaign_popup'),
          '#title' => t(' Campaign Start Date.'),
          '#date_label_position' => 'within',
          '#date_year_range' => '0:+3',
          '#datepicker_options' => array('minDate' => 0),
          '#attributes' => array('readonly' => 'readonly'),
    );
```

Comment: Updated my answer with $date_format. And please consider accepting the answer if you got the solution. Thanks

Comment: readonly works well, but I need timestamp in form state values, this will return date in your format 'd/m/Y H:i'

Comment: You need to use strtotime($form_state['values']['campaign_popup']);